# Encryption - Decryption, Database

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

i created two functions for encryption and decryption like this

```
function encryption($x) {
    $key = 'SuperSecretKey';
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $x, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return $encrypted;
}

function decryption($y) {
    $key = 'SuperSecretKey';
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $y, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

i inserted the encrypted password in databbase its working fine , when i retrieve the password from database i get the encrypted password like this

```
$dpass = "select Password from persons where Email='" . $_POST['name'] . "'";
$rpass = mysql_query($dpass);
$line = mysql_fetch_array($rpass);
$lpass = $line['Password'];
echo $lpass;
```

But the problem is when U use the decryption func

```
$d_pass = decryption($lpass);

echo $d_pass;
```

It dont give me the same text I used for password? Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Don't store encrypted password. Hash them and store in database.

Comment: Aside from that, WTF are you doing using `mysql_query` in 2013?  :P  Check out [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: I see SQL Injection here .... Never trust user Input

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function encryption($x) {
    $key = 'SuperSecretKey';
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $x, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    return $encrypted;
}

function decryption($y) {
    $key = 'SuperSecretKey';
    $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($y), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
    return $decrypted;
}
```